# Going on the previous page with hidden field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I got a problem whan i go to previous page on a form, I want to keep all the data entered on the field (this point is ok) but got a problem with specific field :

I have 2 field which, when fullfilled, put the other one on hidden

```
  function hideElectrodeInterne() {

    var x = document.getElementById("data_entry_form_electrodeInterne");
    if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
      x.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      x.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  }
```

But when i go on this page with a return, the field is fullfilled with previous value but the js doesnt have trigger, which is annoying .
Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: I think the only (simple) solution is to have hidden field in your form which will contain visibility of your field.

Comment: This is what i have. but when going back on this page, the values are fulfilled with previous values, but the js does not trigger and a field which could be hidden (because the other field is fullfilled) is visible.

Comment: In this case, just pass the value back using URL (/previous/url?value_of_posted_field) either through posting form.

Comment: I am not sure to understand, the user just press the return button on the browser to make this problem appear.

Comment: Then you need to use localStorage.setItem before submiting your form. An check value from localStorage before displaying form

Comment: Ok so, storing in the session is a good idea, but how i can check this before displaying the form using the return action ?

Comment: You should check this value on load. Maybe in window.onload function.